# How to retrieve bus stops from OpenStreetMap using Python?

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I'm trying to get all USA bus stops from OSM using this [Biergarten example for Germany](https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-data-from-openstreetmap-with-python-and-the-overpass-api-513882a27fd0) but I haven't achieved that.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import requests
import json

overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
overpass_query = """
[out:json];
area["ISO3166-1"="US"][admin_level=2];
(node["highway"="bus_stop"](area);
 way["highway"="bus_stop"](area);
 rel["highway"="bus_stop"](area);
);
out center;
"""
response = requests.get(overpass_url, 
                        params={'data': overpass_query})
data = response.json()
```

The result is an empty list. I would appreciate any hints on this problem – thanks!

Comment: hi there  - good day dear Francisco - did you have found out more? The Biergarten-example seems to work here. Lets see where you got stuck